# Postgres full text search with multiple columns, why concat in index and not at runtime?

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search

I've come across full text search in postgres in the last few days, and I am a little confused about indexing when searching across multiple columns.

The postgres [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-tables.html) talk about creating a `ts_vector` index on concatenated columns, like so:

```
CREATE INDEX pgweb_idx ON pgweb 
    USING gin(to_tsvector('english', title || ' ' || body));
```

which I can search like so:

```
... WHERE 
      (to_tsvector('english', title||' '||body) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'foo'))
```

However, if I wanted to sometimes search just the title, sometimes just the body, and sometimes both, I would need 3 separate indexes. And if I added in a third column, that could potentially be 6 indexes, and so on.

An alternative which I haven't seen in the docs is just to index the two columns seperately, and then just use a normal `WHERE...OR` query:

```
... WHERE
      (to_tsvector('english', title) @@ to_tsquery('english','foo'))
    OR
      (to_tsvector('english', body) @@ to_tsquery('english','foo'))
```

Benchmarking the two on ~1million rows seems to have basically no difference in performance.

**So my question is:**

Why would I want to concatenate indexes like this, rather than just indexing columns individually? What are the advantages/disadvantages of both?

My best guess is that if I knew in advance I would only want to ever search both columns (never one at a time) I would only ever need one index by concatenating which use less memory.

Comment: I'm not really certain how concatenating the `title` into the `body` and then indexing that would give much value, though I am open to correction. I would probably just stick with indexing them separately. Also, if it was some wacky one-off that somehow required you to concatenate, then I guess you could just run the query ad-hoc.

Comment: You're correct in your guess. I would encourage you to self-answer if no-one else does, Jeopardy style here.

Answer (score 6):

No you don't need separate indexes. Use the weights feature. They are just a label your can query against. You can have up to four labels to query against (A-D).

```
--search any "field" for quick:
select 'quick:1A brown:2B quick:3C'::tsvector @@ 'quick'::tsquery; --true

--search B "field" for quick:
select 'quick:1A brown:2B quick:3C'::tsvector @@ 'quick:B'::tsquery; --false

--search B or C "fields" for quick:
select 'quick:1A brown:2B quick:3C'::tsvector @@ 'quick:BC'::tsquery; --true
```

You might want to concatenate tsvectors, so that you can separately apply weights to them and then put them together:

```
select
  setweight( name_column::tsvector, 'A') || setweight( phone_column::tsvector, 'B');
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually the alternative would be to use where with *OR*, and not *AND*.

If you have index on tsvector(body + title), and you're searching in it, searched words can be in title *OR* in body.

Also - when testing, make sure you have reasonable number of rows in the table.

Simplest case which should show good difference: find two words - one of them that is very likely to be in title. and the other - that is very likely to be in body. But make sure that there is not much of rows that match *both* criteria. For example - you might have 30% of word "depesz" being in body. You also have ~ 30% chance of having "mysql" in title. But having "depesz and mysql" in any of the fields in the same row is very unlikely. And then check performance with such indexes.

Comment: Ha, good spot, on OR vs AND i'll update the question.

I did it with 1Million rows - couldn't be bothered waiting for any more to insert :)

Comment: Thanks for dropping by depesz - we are getting quite a few postgres questions these days so I do hope you'll stick around :-)

Comment: @Jack: not sure I will - I found stackexchange sites less and less usable. I generally try to get RSS, but on stackexchange sites rss is pretty much useless - so much pollution from edition of old questions.

Comment: I've created an rss feed for you [here](http://www.douglastechnology.co.uk/depesz.rss) - are you willing to give that a try? I'm happy to put the effort in filtering out stuff you are unlikely to be interested in to gain the chance to have you more involved in the site :-)

Comment: Jack :) I'll bite - subscribed.

Comment: I'm curious if this http://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/38693/postgresql?sort=newest doesn't give a better feed? I don't know if it gets edit bumps. but since I'm not a religious RSS reader afficionado, I can only surmise.

Comment: @jcolebrand Based on timestamps at these posts - it looks that it sorts based on when given post was edited, and not when it was created.

Comment: That sucks. I figured it did that. Ah well.